# Does rpc Call method run in the same go routine as the server?

Tags: go, rpc

My server:

```
func (t *Arith) Multiply(args *Args, reply *int) error {
    *reply = args.A * args.B
    return nil
}
func main() {
    arith := new(Arith)
    rpc.Register(arith)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()
    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", e)
    }
    go http.Serve(l, nil)
}
```

Client:

`client.Call("Arith.Multiply", args, &reply)`

I think then `Multiply` run in another go routine? The `client.Call()` actually invokes `go server.SomeFun()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each http request has its own goroutine, that's a property of the `http.Server` itself, and `net/rpc` builds on top of it.

From the documentation of [`http.Serve`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve):

> Serve accepts incoming HTTP connections on the listener l, **creating
>   a new service goroutine for each**. The service goroutines read
>   requests and then call handler to reply to them. Handler is typically
>   nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is used.

And from [`rpc.HandleHTTP`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#HandleHTTP):

> **HandleHTTP registers an HTTP handler for RPC messages to DefaultServer on DefaultRPCPath and a debugging handler on
>   DefaultDebugPath.** It is still necessary to invoke http.Serve(),
>   typically in a go statement.

Comment: RPC is also a kind of http request?

Comment: @haoyuan yes, it's served over http.